# Type self referencing type alias

Tags: python, mypy

I would like to have a type that references itself:

```
SelfReferenceType = Dict[str, Union[str, 'SelfReferenceType']]
```

With python 3.5 and latest mypy I get:

```
test.py:1: error: Invalid type "test.SelfReferenceType"
```

Is there an easy way to do this? My guess is that forward references are only supported for classes, not aliases?

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
SelfReferenceType = Dict[str, Union[str, 'SelfReferenceType']]

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {} # type: SelfReferenceType

    # Functions that work on self.data
```

Comment: Unfortunately, mypy currently doesn't support recursive types -- you can track the open issue for it here: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is correct and works in newer versions of Python:

```
SelfReferenceType = Dict[str, Union[str, 'SelfReferenceType']]
```

I tested with 3.10.6 and do not get any errors. It would seem that this has been fixed.

In general using quoted strings for circular or "forward" references is the correct approach as outlined at https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references and [this comment by Guido](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/457#issuecomment-55632367). I couldn't find any information one way or the other about following this pattern for type aliases, specifically, but I don't see any reason why it would be different.

It's also worth nothing that references like this might work without quoting with sufficiently new versions of mypy ([that include this PR](https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/13297), and maybe have a flag enabled).